# Show that $Tf(x) = g(x)f(x), \; \forall x\in [a,b]$ is a bounded linear operator $T \in B(X)$ .

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory

**Exercise :**

> Let $X=C[a,b]$ be equipped with the norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ and $g \in X$. We define the operator $T:X \to X$ to be :
>   $$Tf(x) = g(x)f(x), \; \forall x\in [a,b]$$
>   Show that $T$ is a **Bounded Linear Operator** $(T \in B(X))$.

**Attempt :**

Let $y(x),z(x) \in C[a,b]$. Then, it is :

$$T(y(x)+z(x)) = g(x)(y(x)+z(x)) = g(x)y(x)+g(x)z(x)$$
$$\implies$$
$$T(y(x)+z(x)) = Ty(x) + Tz(x), \; \forall y(x),z(x) \in C[a,b] $$

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and $f(x) \in C[a,b]$. Then :

$$T(\lambda f(x)) = g(x)[\lambda f(x)] = \lambda g(x)f(x)$$
$$\implies$$
$$T(\lambda f(x)) = \lambda f(x), \; \forall \lambda \in \mathbb R, \; \forall f(x) \in C[a,b]$$

Thus, $T$ is indeed linear.

Also, if $f(x),g(x) \in C[a,b]$ then it also is $g(x)f(x) \in C[a,b]$ and thus $T:X \to X$.

For the boundedness, I need to prove that :
$$\exists M>0 : \|Tf(x)\| \leq M \|f(x)\|$$

It is :

$$Tf(x) = g(x)f(x) \Rightarrow \|Tf(x)\|_\infty = \|g(x)f(x)\|_\infty \leq \|g(x)\|_\infty \|f(x)\|_\infty $$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\|Tf(x)\|_\infty \leq \sup\{|g(x)| : x \in X\} \|f(x)\|_\infty $$

$$\|Tf(x)\|_\infty \leq G \|f(x)\|_\infty$$

since $g \in C[a,b]$ and thus $\exists G>0 : |g(x)| \leq G \; \forall x \in C[a,b] \implies G = \sup\{|g(x)| : x \in X\}$.

**Question :** Is my proof correct and rigorous enough ?

Comment: I say "YESSS" $$$$$

Comment: Seems correct and rigorous enough. $\|Tf(x)\|_\infty$ is perfectly bounded as well since $f(x)$ is bounded too.

Comment: Yes. Maybe add a half sentence: we can choose $G$ be $\|g\|_\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs ! @Berci added !